# Tools to enforce a coding style for Javascript

Tags: javascript, coding-style

I need to automatically check the style of javascript sources written by different people. Do you know of a good tool to do it? Integration with emacs would be a plus. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

See [EditorConfig](http://editorconfig.org). This tool is not limited to js though; You first install [the plugin for your editor](http://editorconfig.org#download) (there is an emacs plugin), and create a file named `.editorconfig`, whose content is the coding style.

Answer (score 1):

Google [JavaScript pretty print](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&q=javascript+pretty+print&meta=&aq=f&oq=) and [JavaScript lint](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&q=javascript+lint&meta=). Plenty of options, including [JavaScript Lint](http://www.javascriptlint.com/) and [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/), among others.

Comment: JSHint is not code style tool, rather than code quality tool. Yes, it has some whitespace checking but it's not configurable by any means.

Comment: People already know how to Google, telling them to Google it is not helpful.  Furthermore, JSLint is not a code style tool: it enforces only one code style (Douglas Crockford's).  JSHint is not much better in that regard.

Answer (score 1):

I've recently updated the [CodePainter project](https://github.com/jedhunsaker/codepainter) to work tightly with EditorConfig, so you can get the best of both worlds with JavaScript.

Please, spread the word. The project could use more traction and I could use more help.

Answer (score 0):

There's also [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/) which has libraries for Rhino, JavaScriptCore, Windows Script Host and Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for the JS Code Sniffer: https://npmjs.org/package/jscodesniffer#a-standard