# Javascript code style enforcer or checker

Tags: javascript, coding-style, jslint, jshint

I'm working on a project that uses a specific styleguide for javascript. For instance, an if/else statement would look like this:

```
if( condition ){
  // Bla bla
}
else {
  // Another bla bla
}
```

What I'm looking for is a tool that would allow me to check the syntax of a file according to a specific styleguide. [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/)/[JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) don't focus on style, [Closure Linter](https://developers.google.com/closure/utilities/) is not customizable, and [Uncrustify](http://uncrustify.sourceforge.net/) reformats the file without warning (and doesn't officially support Javascript).

The best output I could get with this program would be the one from Closure Linter but with custom rules. Answers to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395009/tools-to-enforce-a-coding-style-for-javascript) were all wrong.

Does such a tool exist?

Comment: I thought JSLint was mainly about style, although not the style shown in your example

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're still looking for an answer, you could try a project called [jscs](https://github.com/mdevils/node-jscs).
You can customize how your code should look like in almost any aspect, and those which you can't yet are being developed (function argument spacing, for example).

Everything is customizable via a `.jscsrc` file; the following is an example of one of my projects using it:

```
{
    "requireCurlyBraces":                   [ "if", "else", "for", "while", "do", "switch" ],
    "requireSpaceAfterKeywords":            [ "if", "else", "for", "while", "do", "switch" ],
    "disallowSpaceAfterKeywords":           [],
    "requireSpacesInsideObjectBrackets":    "all",
    "disallowSpaceAfterObjectKeys":         true,
    "disallowImplicitTypeConversion":       [],
    "disallowKeywords":                     [ "with" ],
    // ...
}
```

If you're using Grunt, feel free to try my own task for jscs - which is [grunt-jscs-checker](https://github.com/gustavohenke/grunt-jscs-checker).

BTW, [the jQuery team](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/c462e66f5d2c3da30879e38649e81d34bb7d2587/package.json#L66) [is using jscs](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/5ce0b342577076a4355ba1bb0ad0aef98261f236/package.json#L38) :)

Comment: Take a look at the edit I've made. Maybe it's something you care about!

Comment: Can we use jscs for CoffeeScript files?

Comment: @ankakusu No. They're completely different languages, but who knows, maybe forking jscs...?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're really after a [JavaScript beautifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18985). Checking can be done via "run it over the files and see if they change" backed by version control.

Answer (score 0):

There is no tool matching your desires. JSLint is applying the style rules Crockford advices (and enforces), JSHint is more flexible, in that you can choose the rules that better suits your coding style, but is not flexible enough to enforce any kind of style.

Usually, you configure your editor so it helps you indent and do the newlines the same way you like your code to be. And use the linter to watch out where it matters (some whitespacing rules, how to use parens…). The role of the linter is more a guard against stupid mistakes from which your language does not prevent you.